# web app opening external URL without leaving web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, iphone-web-app

I have a web app. The web app is added to home screen on iPhone. I have many external resources(Links) in my web app. Every time a link is clicked, it opens the web browser because target is set to _blank and there is no way for the user to go back. is it possible that the user will be able to open any of these resources without leaving my web app?

I was thinking of doing the following:
creating an iframe and have the links open within that iframe. I am hoping that there is something better out there.

If you still not sure what is it that I want?

a good example would be, if you look at facebook's native app for iPhone when you click on an article that someone posted, it opens the link within a frame that allow you to go back to your last page. In other words, you never leave their app. I understand that it is a native app and it is completely different but I believe that with JQuery Mobile or just JQuery it is possible. Am I wrong?

Comment: jQuery-Mobile isn't a plugin, it's a framework. Tag removed.

Comment: I did not say it was a plugin. I thought there might be a way using it to do what I need.